# Why unity 2019.4, sub thread can call unity api?

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine

In before, I know sub thread cant call unity api which can only be called in unity main thread. but recently I wirte a demo. it works , I am confused. Could someone tell me the reseaon. I use unity in version 2019.4.
code just like this:

```
    public void TestThread(){
        Thread thread = new Thread( ()=>{
            Thread.Sleep(3300);
            TestUnityFun();
        } );
        thread.Start(); 
    }

    public void TestUnityFun()
    {
        if (testGameOB != null)
        {
            testGameOB.SetActive(!testGameOB.activeSelf);
        }
    }
```

Could someone tell me the reseaon. Thanks

Comment: In unity editor tell error.  bug this works on Android project.

Comment: I checked the code you pasted, and in line with expectations, it throws UnityException: get_gameObject can only be called from the main thread.

Comment: I found the error in unity editor. But it works fine when running on android.

Answer (score 0):

This may cause crash in a low probability on android.